# Trying to install python-social-auth, get ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages'

Tags: python, django

Question title says it all. I'm not a Python expert, not sure where to go from here. I tried everything I could think of.

I'm using pip3 and python3 with Django 1.8.

Following instructions from https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth I did `sudo pip3 install python-social-auth` and all the dependencies.

Shell output:

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from social.utils import setting_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/social/utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages'
```

I'm not sure why the `python-social-auth` module tries to call requests.packages since that does not seem to exist in the "requests" module.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.

```
sudo pip3 install requests --upgrade
```

Fixed it by upgrading my system's "requests" package.

Answer (score 1):

this question may be getting a bunch of new visitors...

requests.packages has been removed from requests: 
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/4067

install the vendored libraries separately

`pip install urllib3`